# ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheel (dash-bootstrap-components)

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install packages in an offline manner. However, when I downloaded all packages and tried to install these packages on another computer, some error has emerged as shown in the following figure. This seems like it is failed to install the "dash-bootstrap-components" package. How can I solve it?

By the way, the "dash-bootstrap-components" package is packaged as a "tar.gz" file, does this causes the failure?

The following commands can reproduce the problem even on the same computer:

```sh
pip download dash-bootstrap-components
pip install --no-index --find-links ./ dash-bootstrap-components
```

My goal is to configure a python environment on a network-free computer. If this method is unavailable, is there any other methods that can work around it?

[image: Error]

[image: Package]

Comment: using `--no-index --find-links ./ ` options means that you are not going to look in global PyPI and going to install everything from the current directory, but there is no [`wheel` package distribution](https://pypi.org/project/wheel/#files) so `pip` tells you exactly that

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Thanks a lot! I have solved my problem by manually downloading the "wheel" package from the internet and put it into the folder.

Comment: download the "wheel" package place it into  the internet folder

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have solved this problem by manually download the "[wheel](https://pypi.org/project/wheel/#files)" package from the internet and put it into the folder.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for removing my headache!

Comment: @zhenlingcn: Which folder you are talking about?